# Php or Javascript to load data into form elements?

Tags: javascript, php

Right now I'm loading data from a database into form elements via php but I'm wondering if I should create objects in javascript and load them that way.  I could create a php function that returns a json array and populate an object that way via an ajax call.

I currently save any changes on the form as serializing the form and sending it to a php script to save to the database but with javascript objects I could use data binding and just save the changes to the actual object.

Current Code

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $data['firstname'] ?>">
```

Comment: If you are talking client-side javascript than my feeling is you should stick to php - that way you don't have to account for graceful degradation in your form processing. Of course, without knowing more about the application context it is difficult to be certain. Where and how are you using this data?

Comment: The data is loaded into the form elements for the user to be able to change.  Basically when the form is submitted I have an ajax call that sends the form data to a php script that save it to a database.

Answer (score 0):

If it advantages you you could have something like this

```
<form>
<input name="bla" id="bla">
<input name="bla1" id="bla1">
<!--etcetera just an example-->
</form>

<script>
var values = <?php echo json_encode(array('bla'=>'value1', 'bla2'=>'value 2')); ?>; //you can also get this via ajax - see docs here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
$.each(values, function( index, value ) {
$('#'+index).val(value); //you can use other selectors if you want to use the name attribute but this should work
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it: SPA concept using Angular, React or Vue:

- define a model with an url to you php file
- bind the model to your form
- define a JS controller which does the frontend middleware

In SPA, your php backend just sends json, the rendering process is completely done in the frontend. That's called headless. Doing so, you got a few benefits:

- data binding, one or two way
- intelligent prefetch of sites, so that it feels like just instant load